# Creating custom color for a phone number

Tags: java, swing, colors

I am making a chat application and in my chats I want to highlight the name and phone number with an unique color generated from the phone number.

So far my implementation is quite naive

```
float alpha=phone number/9999999999.0d /*phone number is 10 digits so this yeild a normalised value from (0-1)*/

Color color=new Color((int)(255*alpha),(int)(200*alpha),(int)(225*alpha)):/*the random values are just to create some varity*/
```

But with similar phone numbers (which occurs quite often) I get the same color.

Any suggestions on how to make each phone number appear distinct and bright like in whatsapp for example?the same phone number must give back the same color every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a series of colors that is your 'palette'
then do a mod() calculation on the number and use that as an index into the palette.